# How to prevent closing of bootstrap modal on mobile device on tapping/touching the area inside the modal (except the close buttons)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with using a bootstrap modal to display items in my online portfolio. Everything works fine on a computer. However when I open the modal on a mobile device and tap anywhere inside the modal it automatically closes it. I only want it to close when user taps close buttons, otherwise I can't use a carousel, or a form, or a video inside the modal because it closes it as soon as you touch controls. I used agency bootstrap theme as a start point for my online portfolio. See a draft of my portfolio page at http://www.spdesign.org/2017/ Here is the example of html that I am using for opening modal:

```
<a href="#portfolioModal-posters-1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><img src="img/simages/graphic design/posters/5.jpg" alt=""></a>

<!-- Portfolio Modal 1 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal-posters-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
                            <h2>Poster Design</h2>
                            <p class="item-intro text-muted">Poster designed for Center for Translational and Basic Research (former Gene Center) at Hunter College, City Iniversity of New York</p>
                            <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="img/bimages/graphic design/posters/5.jpg" alt="">
                            <p>Creative concept, Poster and other promotional materials designed to promote conferences and seminars orginized by The Office of Diversity Affairs at New York University School of Medicine</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it is working fine on my iphone if i click those posters and the modal opens and it only closes on clicking the button.

Comment: <a href="" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal-posters-1"><img src="img/simages/graphic design/posters/5.jpg" alt=""></a>

Comment: <!-- Portfolio Modal 1 -->
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade"  id="portfolioModal-posters-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

Comment: <div class="lr">
                        <div class="rl">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- Project Details Go Here -->

Comment: <h2>Poster Design</h2>
                                <p class="item-intro text-muted">Poster designed for Center for Translational and Basic Research (former Gene Center) at Hunter College, City Iniversity of New York</p>
                                <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="img/bimages/graphic design/posters/5.jpg" alt="">
                                <p>Creative concept, Poster and other promotional materials designed to promote conferences of The Office of Diversity Affairs at NYU School of Medicine</p>

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: Thank you for your comment Timmy, I am not sure how I can show the full html code here. I pasted the html code related to opening one modal by clicking the thumbnail. When I click the first thumbnail the modal closes only on clicking close button, but when I click the first thumbnail for a second time or when I click other thumbnail something goes wrong on my android phone - modals start closing on tapping anywhere withing the modal. I guess something happens during the first thumbnail click that affects all consequent clicks or how the other modals close, I just can't figure what it is.